# POST with AFNetworking, error code -1001

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I want to POST a json message to send to a server. I don't have access to the server itself but I know it is working and set up to return a success/failure message when a message gets through. The server requires an app id and password to connect

I am using AFNetworking for this. Here is the code I'm using:

```
NSURL* pushServerURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://myserverurl.com/"];
AFHTTPClient* networkInstance = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL: pushServerURL];

NSDictionary *parameters =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"myappid", @"app_id", @"mypassword", @"password", nil];

NSDictionary *params =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       parameters, @"user", nil];

[networkInstance postPath: @"users/login.json"
               parameters: params
                  success:^
 (AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id jsonResponse)
{
    NSLog (@"SUCCESS");
}
                  failure:^
(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"FAILED");
}];
```

It always fails with the error code -1001.

The NSError has 4 keys in the user info

```
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey with value @"http://myserverurl.com/, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey with value <not an Objective-C object>, 
NSLocalizedDescription with value "The request timed out"
NSUnderlyingError and the value has no string.
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: -1001 usually means that the request timed out. Is your network working properly?

Comment: Any chance we can get error description coming with the error code? And what about trying same with native `NSURLConnection`?

Comment: The network should be working correctly. Several other apps are using it at the moment and working correctly. I have no idea how to use NSURLConnection, I'm firmly outside my comfort zone with this network programming stuff. The error returned 4 keys which say NSErrorFailingURLStringKey with a value myurl, NSErrorFailingURLKey with value <not an Objective-C object>, NSLocalizedDescription with value "The request timed out" and NSUnderlyingError and the value has no string. I'll update the question to include these error strings.

Comment: You already described the error in the updated post: `the request timed out`. Most probably the URL you are trying to post to is not reachable. Try to access it with Safari. Provided that it responds to GET requests, this experiment should reveal connectivity errors. Otherwise, if connectivity is Ok, but POST is not an allowed method, then you'll get an error from the server corresponding to that reason.

Comment: Yup, the server is the issue. I tried it with a different server and it worked fine. Not sure what to do for the answer to this question as it's in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line of code. You can easily find what is the response coming from server or else, where the actual problem is?

```
[networkInstance postPath: @"users/login.json"
           parameters: params
              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id jsonResponse) {
  NSLog (@"SUCCESS");
}
              failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@" Error - Statistics file upload failed: \"%@\"", [request error]);
}];
```

Comment: Where do I call this? and where do I find/create the ASIHTTPRequest object to pass into it?

Comment: That comment was directed at the question which has since been edited so the comment doesn't make any sense. I'm not using ASIHTTPRequest, I was asking about it because it was in the answer and I didn't understand.